# Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cucumber

I have a project I'm trying to set up on a Continuous Integration server, that is running Bamboo.  Everything's been going great until I try to run cucumber tests, where I get this error:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec cucumber 
/home/BAMBOO/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/LIMS-PLAN-JOB1/
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in 
`encode': "\xD8" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
```

Now, I've googled and googled on this and everyone's solutions seem to be to do export LANG=en_US.utf8 and it suddenly works.  Not in my case.

I've tried all of the suggestions that I've seen so far in google searches, between different forums, github issues, etc.  Nothing seems to work, and I can't pin it down to anything.  Cucumber of course works on both my mac and my linux desktop for this project, and as near as I can tell, has the same locale settings.

Here's my locale -a, if it helps.  If you need something else, ask away.

```
C
C.utf8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Crazy timing... but I *think* updating to gherkin 2.11.3 which JUST came out a few hours ago, did the trick.